# MongoDb. Get an object in a nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like this one:

```
{
    "_id" : "bc923adf-ddd9-4987-a759-2d3f8dbffe3e",
    "title" : "DocumentTitle",        
    "nestedObjects" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "3eef3a60-8d70-4640-b494-cb17e52e73a7",
            "startTime" : "21:00:00",
            "endTime" : "00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "5aa8ca60-8d70-4640-b494-cb17e52e4caa",
            "startTime" : "17:00:00",
            "endTime" : "23:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a query to get the 'nestedObject' that matches both Ids, root object Id and nested object Id. For instance, given root object Id equals "bc923adf-ddd9-4987-a759-2d3f8dbffe3e" and nested object Id equals "5aa8ca60-8d70-4640-b494-cb17e52e4caa", I want to get this result:

```
{
   "_id" : "5aa8ca60-8d70-4640-b494-cb17e52e4caa",
   "startTime" : "17:00:00",
   "endTime" : "23:00:00"
}
```

I tried with this query;

```
var nestedObject = db.myCollection.aggregate(
[
    { "$match" : { "_id" : "bc923adf-ddd9-4987-a759-2d3f8dbffe3e" } }, 
    { "$unwind" : "$nestedObjects" }, 
    { "$match" : { "nestedObjects._id" : "5aa8ca60-8d70-4640-b494-cb17e52e4caa" } }, 
    { "$project" : { "startTime" : "$nestedObjects.startTime", "endTime":"$nestedObjects.endTime" } }
]);
```

I expected to be able to access `starTime` and `endTime` properties using `nestedObject.startTime` with no luck. Also, I'd like to get the whole nested object without the need of listing all its properties in the `project` phase.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier query I could run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `$project` stage with a `$replaceRoot`:

```
{ "$replaceRoot" : { newRoot: "$nestedObjects" } }
```